# How to correctly use the "AND" operator in Prisma?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, next.js, orm, prisma

I have 2 models. Database management system Postgres

```
model Product {
 id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
 name        String   @unique
 description String?
 options     Option[]

 @@map("products")
}

model Option {\
 id                      Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
 title                   String?
 description             String?
 productId               Int
 product                 Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id]
 @@map("options")
}
```

I want to filter "Products" by the related table "Option" for this I use the following expression

```
const product = await this.prismaService.product.findMany({
        where: {
            options: {
                some: {
                    AND: [
                        {
                            title: 'square',
                            description: '20',
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'type',
                            description: 'invertor',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        },
        include: { options: true },
    });
```

With this expression, I will get an empty array, and the “OR” operator will work as it should. And even if I place one object in the "AND" array, I will also get the correct filtering.  Please indicate what I'm doing wrong and help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right solution, the authorship is not mine, the guys helped me find it.

```
        const product = await this.prismaService.product.findMany({
        where: {
            AND: [
                { price: 21.99 },
                { options: { some: { title: 'invertor', description: '25' } } },
                { options: { some: { title: 'type', description: 'invertor' } } },
                { options: { some: { title: 'WiFi:', description: 'yes' } } },
            ],
        },
        include: { options: true },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue might be related to the way you are using the **AND** operator within the **some** filter. The **some** filter is designed to check if at least one element in the array satisfies the conditions, and the **AND** operator inside it might not be working as expected.

**You can try below update version - old**

```
const product = await this.prismaService.product.findMany({
  where: {
    options: {
      every: {
        OR: [
          { title: 'square', description: '20' },
          { title: 'type', description: 'invertor' },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  include: { options: true },
});
```

I replaced the **some** filter with the **every** filter and used **OR** conditions within it. This should find products that have at least one option with either the specified title and description

**New Query**

```
const product = await this.prismaService.product.findMany({
  where: {
    options: {
      some: {
        title: 'square',
        description: '20',
      },
      some: {
        title: 'type',
        description: 'invertor',
      },
    },
  },
  include: { options: true },
});
```

I separated the some filters for each condition. This should retrieve products that have at least one option with the first set of conditions (title: 'square', description: '20') and at least one option with the second set of conditions (title: 'type', description: 'invertor').

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution also does not provide all samples, I discovered this after a thorough check. And when we add a third field, "findMany" returns an empty array.

Comment: please check the updated code version

Comment: Swears TS - An object literal cannot have several properties with the same name. And when TS is disabled, it does not provide proper filtering

Comment: First of all start with simple postgresql query and achieve the targeted result and then try to convert it to Prisma version